# ADB Start activity name doesn't work

Tags: android, shell, adb

I dumped and logged a few things in ADB with my Galaxy Note 3.
Logcat gave me following line:

```
    #party pause(  870): onReceive android.intent.action.ACTIVITY_STATE/th.in.siamgame.ggplay.mwcasia/resume
```

And another dumpfile told me that the package name is :

```
    th.in.siamgame.ggplay.mwcasia
```

I tried a few variations of my ADB Start command.

```
    adb shell am start -n th.in.siamgame.ggplay.mwcasia/th.in.siamgame.ggplay.mwcasia.resume

    adb shell am start -n th.in.siamgame.ggplay.mwcasia/.resume
```

On both of those commands also with

```
    -a android.intent.action.ACTIVITY_STATE
```

I hope you guys can help me with starting that app via ADB.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Proper syntax of the command is:

```
adb shell am start -n package/.activity
```

For example:

```
adb shell am start -n com.example/.ActivityName
```

It seems `resume` isn't the name of activity. You can find main activity name in the `AndroidManifest.xml` (if you have source code of course). It's the one with the attributes in intent filter:

```
<action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
<category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
```

If you don't have source code, but have apk file, you still can find it with the aapt tool. aapt located in the `<android-sdk-path>/build-tools/<version>/aapt`.
Start it with command `aapt l -a filename.apk` and you will get output like this:

```
N: android=http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android
  E: manifest (line=2)
    A: android:versionCode(0x0101021b)=(type 0x10)0xc
    A: android:versionName(0x0101021c)="1.0.1" (Raw: "1.0.1")
    A: package="com.example" (Raw: "com.example")
    E: application (line=8)
      A: android:theme(0x01010000)=@0x7f0d0022
      A: android:label(0x01010001)=@0x7f0b0000
      A: android:icon(0x01010002)=@0x7f020002
      A: android:name(0x01010003)="AppName" (Raw: "AppName")
      A: android:debuggable(0x0101000f)=(type 0x12)0x0
      E: activity (line=15)
        A: android:label(0x01010001)=@0x7f0b0000
        A: android:name(0x01010003)=".MainActivity" (Raw: ".MainActivity")
        A: android:launchMode(0x0101001d)=(type 0x10)0x2
        A: android:configChanges(0x0101001f)=(type 0x11)0xb0
        E: intent-filter (line=21)
          E: action (line=22)
            A: android:name(0x01010003)="android.intent.action.MAIN" (Raw: "android.intent.action.MAIN")
          E: category (line=25)
            A: android:name(0x01010003)="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" (Raw: "android.intent.category.LAUNCHER")
 ... etc ...
```

And again you need `"android.intent.action.MAIN"` and `"android.intent.category.LAUNCHER"`. It is `.MainActivity` in the example.

Comment: Damn Sergey, you are awesome ! Thank you very much. Since your instructions I knew what to look for and luckily noticed that the developer called it "Mainactiviy" instead of "Mainactivity" :D this was my working line of code now: "adb shell am start -n th.in.siamgame.ggplay.mwcasia/.Mainactiviy"

Answer (score 1):

Use the action MAIN to start your app rather than ACTIVITY_STATE.  ACTIVITY_STATE is an internal system action which is only sent by the framework:

```
-a android.intent.action.MAIN
```